# commits in PR are not seen in git log

Tags: git, github

I had created pull request with 5 different commits, which I wanted to squash into single commit.

On that branch ( on local machine ) I executed git log command but didn't see these 5 commits. 
It shows commits from upstream ( main project ) + last commit to forked branch. 
I'm not sure what happened to other 4 commits on my forked branch.

Later I end up messing up whole things as I executed command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

How can I see same commits as on branch in pull request, on my machine locally?

Comment: @Melebius thanks for quick review, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

1. `git reflog` to see all that was ever done on the local branch
2. `git checkout -b newbranchname referencenumber_of_last_commit` to take it back to the last commit `if you so desire`

Then to see the commits on local branch as in `pull request`:
try the steps [here](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-active-pull-request-locally)

Or simply do:

> 1. git fetch origin
> 2. git checkout -b b2 origin/b2

But the link above would be most helpful.